# How would life on Earth change if Earth unexpectedly entered an eternal never ending night?

Tags: society, civilization, day-night

This question is obviously not plausible, let's just say this somehow works because of magic.

One night, the Sun unexpectedly and out of no where simply does not rise in the morning and then soon after the entire Earth is slowly covered in an eternal night. The Sun is absent, but the moon is still present **and shines light as if the Sun still reflected light off its surface.**

Temperatures in regions generally remain towards the average night time temperatures seen in their respective areas today, with the usual seasonal fluctuations. The lack of sunlight does not cause the planet to cool. **The Earth continues to orbit, rotate and act as if the Sun was still there. It's just practically invisible because.. magic.**

How would this affect life on Earth? Both human society and animal life.

**Edit: I think generally, the light and heat is still there. It's just invisible. This is why the planet does not cool. So photosynthesis should still occur. Maybe in 12 hour cycles.**

Comment: If the sunlight is still technically there, as you said it still spreads heat to the planet, and it's just invisible, would plants still be able to use it for photosynthesis? If so, then most plant life would survive for a while before undergoing a mass extinction, but if not, then every living thing on Earth would die within a few hundred years (with the exception of some extremophiles and anything on a food chain with a basis of chemosynthetic bacteria).

Comment: @Snowshard Yeah I'm going to slightly diverge off here because I find this detail more fascinating. In all accords the light / heat is still there, it's just invisible. If this was the case, why would plants still undergo a mass extinction?

Comment: Since light would no longer be visible, all animals that relied on light to see would die very quickly, and that would have massive affects on the biosphere, such as less carbon dioxide in the atmosphere and less plant eaters (which seems like a good thing, but it would probably have some unintended consequences).

Comment: @Snowshard Fascinating. I'm sure nocturnal animals would love the change.. but maybe there would no longer be any prey left for them to eat.

Comment: Only the light from the Sun is invisible, and the moon still reflects imaginary light as if the Sun was still shining on it. So creatures should still have vision.

Comment: @ Noble Well, having moonlight definitely changes things; that could lead to some pretty interesting adaptations with the circadian rhythm changing to a lunar-based schedule. There would still be a mass extinction, but humans, being by far the most adaptable species on the planet, would probably be able to survive this event, albeit in very small numbers.

Comment: @Noble How do you define 'invisible' after your edit? Because physically both photosynthesis and 'seeing' are based on the interaction of protein complexes with light of very similar wavelengths.

Comment: Everything but chemosynthetic bacteria would die in fairly short order.  Light of the frequencies used in photosynthesis can't be invisible, unless you magically change the chemistry of the receptors in the eyes.

Comment: Asking how something would affect "society" is pretty generally considered to be too broad. You are asking not only about the human society, but also animal life and life in general. Consider narrowing this down to ask about some *specific* aspect; for example, asking how the scenario would affect human farming might still be broad, but it would be a whole lot less broad than what you have right now.

Answer (score 3):

**Colour Vision goes out of style in Non-Human animals**

Now that light is "invisible" , All of the Evolutionary Advantages that having colour vision gave goes out the window. Colour is unidentifiable in very low light , which means that theirs no real point in investing brain and eye power on colour vision anymore. This also translates over to organism that are colourful to transfer meaning to colour vision animals. Flowers turn white and gray , Butterflies become like or are replaced by moths , songbirds turn brown , etc. Also , their is a mass extinction of animal that have heavily invested on seeing in color or being seen in color. Owls replace Hawks and Eagles as masters of the sky , Bats out-compete birds and become WAY more common , the Octopus loses its powers , and things of that nature. Basically , **all Diurnal animals either adapt of go extinct**

**Flashlight and Power Companies have a Field Day**

Human power consumption goes WAY up. Growing nearly 100% over night (If you'll excuse the pun). Now that people *need* to light their homes for their entire waking period , power company revenue skyrockets and they can  charge whatever they want ( Though it's not like they can't do it already ). Due to this , more and more people will instead rely on generators for power. Poorer areas will be characterized by being dark ( though it's not like they aren't already ) , and cities will use a SHIT TON of energy ( excuse my language ). Also , flashlights will be needed for all daily outdoor activities , so they become as essential as toothbrushes , and Flashlight companies also make a killing.

**Walks become less common as the World becomes more Dangerous**

Most crime happens at night because its night , especially violent crime. If night becomes permanent , then crime rates dramatically go up. Walks become much less common , especially in urban areas , and daytime activities like going to the park and going fishing nearly vanish all together. Due to this , societies become much more indoorsy , and weapons like guns and knives become more of a household item across most countries and cultures.

Also , sleep  cycles become much more arbitrary , while the schedule of daily life remains loosely based off of life before eternal night simply due to the fact that post-night time-of-day schedules are well establish , yet become less and less important as time goes on due to the arbitrarity of the sleep cycle which heavily impacted pre-night daily schedules.

Comment: Considering the clarification I have added to my original post, how would this change your stance / opinion?

Comment: @Noble Its been done